# Guarded function calls in C

Tags: c, debugging, assert, specifications

I want to achieve the following:

Suppose we have some function `foo`. We also have two function `pre` and `post` that check its precondition and postcondition respectively.
We have some `foo` function calls. Now I want to replace each `foo` call with a "guarded" call that checks if the conditions are satisfied. This has to be switchable using a compiler flag. Recursive `foo` calls also have to be replaced.

The best thing I could think of follows:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
int foo_orig(int n);

int foo(int n)
{
    int r;
    assert(pre(n));
    r = foo_orig(n);
    assert(post(n, r));
    return r;
}

int foo_orig(int n)
#else
int foo(int n)
#endif
{
    /* The body of the function foo... */
    foo(n); /* recursive call */
}
```

I know this is clumsy and ugly. Is there any better way to do it? Preferably I would like just to have a macro that does everything automatically, i.e.

```
GUARD(foo, pre, post, arguments, return_type)
```

Is that possible at all?

***EDIT***

Suggestion has been made to embed `pre` and `post` calls into `foo` body. This might work with `pre`, but for `post` we would need to replace every return statement with a rather complicated code. This will also not work if argument values have been changed inside `foo` body.

So this is even more typing. I want something simple and easy to use.

Comment: it sounds like you should implement your own runtime engine'

Comment: Can you just add your `pre()` and `post()` calls to `foo()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if 1
#define foo(...) GUARD(foo, pre, post, (__VA_ARGS__))
#define GUARD(F, PRE, POST, ARGS) (POST(F(PRE ARGS)))

//exactly equivalent to #define foo(...) post(foo(pre(__VA_ARGS__))) 
#endif

int pre(int n) { printf("pre %d\n", n); return n; }
int post(int n) { printf("post %d\n", n); return n; }

int (foo)(int n) {
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return n == 0 ? 0 : foo(n - 1);
}

int main(void) {
    foo(6);
}
```

One feature of `#define`d macros is that they aren't allowed to expand recursively, so you can always define a macro like `#define foo(X) foo(Y(X))` - the `foo` in the expansion is left alone, and marked for no further replacement. It's specifically intended for uses like this, so that a function call can be seamlessly replaced by a wrapped version of the same call, without needing to rename it, for debugging or other such purposes.

(Note that macros, being unaware of C's syntax, will replace the *declaration* of `foo` as well given the chance, which is no good; normally you'd place the macro definition after the body or in a different file, but if you need the wrapper to be recursive, you can also head it off by using the little-known parenthesized function name syntax)

Comment: The parenthesis hack made it. Thanks.

Comment: That should work fine as long as the guarded function takes exactly one argument, but it will need an adjustment if the same is needed in other cases.  It could be done with the comma operator, though.

Comment: Note, too, that as written it doesn't quite match the OP's specs because the postcondition function is supposed to take as arguments the original function arguments as well as its return value.  That, too, could be fixed.

Comment: I assumed the OP's main problem was the name replacement; *most* of the other concerns can be addressed by changing the shape of the macro (depends mainly on whether double-evaluation is going to be a problem).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.  The `NDEBUG` macro is normally used to *suppress* debug code (assertions, specifically), not to cause debug code to be included.  Anyway, yes, you can create a macro that will do this for you in a reusable way.  The need to insert the return value into the arguments of the postcondition function does mean you need a variadic macro, however.

For example:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define GUARD(ret, f, pre, post, ...) \
ret f ( __VA_ARGS__ )
#else
#define GUARD(ret, f, pre, post, ...) \
ret f##_orig ( __VA_ARGS__ );         \
ret f ( __VA_ARGS__ ) {               \
    ret r;                            \
    assert(pre ( __VA_ARGS__ ));      \
    r = f##_orig ( __VA_ARGS__ );     \
    assert(post(r, __VA_ARGS__ ));    \
    return r;                         \
}                                     \
ret f##_orig ( __VA_ARGS__ )
#endif
```

You would use it like so:

```
GUARD(int, foo, pre, post, int n)
{
    /* body of the real foo() */
}
```

If you were willing to use a standard pattern for the `pre` and `post` functions (e.g. `foo_pre()` and `foo_post()`) then you could omit those from the macro arguments and construct them via token pasting, as the `foo_orig` name also is constructed.  Then uses would look like this:

```
GUARD(int, foo, int n)
{
    /* body of the real foo() */
}
```